# MYSQL: stored procedure, insert a row and then select it via LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, last-insert-id

I am trying to make a stored procedure call AddCluster
witch is taking to parameter 'title' and 'alt'

**Case 1:**

If 'title' is in the db then just return the "old" row!

**Case 2:**

If the 'title' is NOT in the db then,

insert a row base on parmerer 'title' and 'alt'

and then select the newly added row via LAST_INSERT_ID()

*The problem is on case 2 it only returns empty!!*

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- AddCluster Group Routines
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`linkbay_dk`@`%` PROCEDURE `AddCluster`(in in_title varchar(45), in in_alt text)
BEGIN
    /* check if 'in_title' is in db */
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT count(*) FROM Cluster 
        WHERE title=in_title 
    )
    THEN
        /* returns old Cluster there is in db */
        SELECT * FROM Cluster WHERE title=in_title; 
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Cluster
        (
            `id`,
            `create_at`,
            `title`,
            `alt`
        )
        VALUES
        (
            null,
            NOW(),
            in_title,
            in_alt
        );
        /* returns the newly added Cluster */
        SELECT * FROM Cluster WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little update.
I find the error.. Which is `count(*)`

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Cluster WHERE title=in_title
```

It should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Cluster WHERE title=in_title
```

See the hole update stored procedure [here!](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1002364/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to INSERT without specifying an id :

```
...
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Cluster
    (
        `create_at`,
        `title`,
        `alt`
    )
    VALUES
    (
        NOW(),
        in_title,
        in_alt
    );
    /* returns the newly added Cluster */
    ...
```

Make sure `Cluster.id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, only that way you can obtain the value with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: Just try it without specifying the id... AUTO_INCREMENT is on, but no luck :(

Comment: If you run the INSERT and SELECT query from the command line, does it work as expected?

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench but yes form the SQL Editor I can make INSERT and SELECT query against the 'Cluster' table... And I can call AddCluster() and it returns a row in case 1, but not on case 2..